# Javafx listen for Control changes in a Panel

Tags: java, javafx, controls, panel

I want to add a change listener for every control in a panel. I want it to be robust, so whenever I change fxml file, I wouldn't have to alter the code that listens for changes in controls.

I have figured a way to add a listener for a specific type of control.

```
panel.getChildren()
     .stream()
     .filter(node -> node instanceof TextField).forEach(node ->
            ((TextField) node).textProperty()
                .addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                        //execute some code
                 }));
```

However I would need to a add similar code to every type of control I intend to use in a panel for this to work.

```
panel.getChildren()
     .stream()
     .filter(node -> node instanceof TextField).forEach(node ->
            ((TextField) node).textProperty()
                .addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                        //execute some code
                 }));

panel.getChildren()
     .stream()
     .filter(node -> node instanceof TextArea).forEach(node ->
            ((TextArea) node).textProperty()
                .addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                        //execute some code
                 }));

//and so on...

panel.getChildren()
     .stream()
     .filter(node -> node instanceof ComboBox).forEach(node ->
            ((ComboBox<?>) node).valueProperty()
                .addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                        //execute some code
                 }));
```

What I want to do is.

I've a document editor that has a panel with controls, so whenever user changes one of that controls preset value, panel with save and cancel buttons would be enabled. Also if user tried to exit a program, without canceling or saving a document, a warning would pop up asking him if he wants to discard changes and exit or cancel.

However I intend to do a lot of changes to document structure, so I will need to add and remove controls from panel constantly. So I need the best way to add this type of listener for every control in a panel in one go.

Comment: There's no way to do this (though I'm not entirely clear what it is you actually want to do). There's no single uniform property for all controls that you could listen to. For example, `TextField`s have `textProperty`, `CheckBox`s have `selectedProperty`, `ComboBox`s have `valueProperty`, along with an `editor` that (typically) has a `textProperty`; `ListView`s and `TableView`s have `selectionModel`s that have a `selectedItem` property, etc etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should write (extend) your own controls and use them in your application. In them you can implement all specific tracking logic as @James_D mentioned. Such an extended TextField should look like this:

```
public class TrackableTextField extends javafx.scene.control.TextField {

    private StringProperty originalText = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(this, "originalText");
    public final String getOriginalText() { return originalText.get(); }
    public final void setOriginalText(String value) { 
        originalText.set(value);
        setText(value);
    }
    public final StringProperty originalTextProperty() { return originalText; }

    private final ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper dirty = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(this, "dirty", false);
    public final boolean isDirty() { return dirty.get(); }
    public final ReadOnlyBooleanProperty dirtyProperty() { return dirty.getReadOnlyProperty(); }

    public TrackableTextField() {
        init();
    }

    public TrackableTextField(String text) {
        init();
        setOriginalText(text);
    }

    private void init() {
        textProperty().addListener( e -> {
            dirty.set(!Objects.equals(getOriginalText(), getText()));
        } );
    }

    public void rollback() {
        setText(getOriginalText());
    }

    public void commit() {
        setOriginalText(getText());
    }
}
```

and a usage example may be like

```
public class Test extends Application {

    private TrackableTextField tf_name = new TrackableTextField();
    private TrackableTextField tf_sname = new TrackableTextField();

    private Button save = new Button("Save");
    private Button discard = new Button("Discard");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        GridPane root = new GridPane();

        root.add(new Label("Name: "), 0, 0);
        root.add(tf_name, 1, 0);

        root.add(new Label("Surname: "), 0, 1);
        root.add(tf_sname, 1, 1);

        root.add(save, 0, 2);
        root.add(discard, 1, 2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        initialize();

    }

    private void initialize() {

        save.setDisable(true);
        discard.setDisable(true);

        save.disableProperty().bind(tf_name.dirtyProperty().or(tf_sname.dirtyProperty()).not());
        discard.disableProperty().bind(tf_name.dirtyProperty().or(tf_sname.dirtyProperty()).not());

        tf_name.setOriginalText("guleryuz");
        tf_sname.setOriginalText("guleryuz");

        save.setOnAction( e -> {
            tf_name.commit();
            tf_sname.commit();
        } );

        discard.setOnAction( e -> {
            tf_name.rollback();
            tf_sname.rollback();
        } );

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```